# How to use SuperLU object to get the inverse of matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I am trying to get matrix inverse from SuperLU object.
I have tried the following:

```
lu = sp.linalg.splu(A)
I = np.eye(A.shape[0])
invA = lu.solve(I)
x = invA.dot(b)
```

The `x` I got is different from executing `x = sp.linalg.solve(b)`. I have also tried doing `invA.dot(A)` and the resulting matrix is **not** the identity matrix.

Comment: *"The x I got is different from executing x = sp.linalg.solve(b)."*  What is `sp.linalg.solve`?  Is the `A` argument missing in that function call?   Please show the import statements that define `sp`, and make sure all the code that you include in the question is something that we can run.  Ideally, you should include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, when you say you get different results, how big is the difference?  Given the inherent imprecision of floating point representation, you can't (in general) expect two different numerical methods to give *exactly* the same answers.

Comment: The matrix A I am using is 6449*6449 in size. After computing A*invA the result on the diagonal is off by approximately .003 and other places (where they should be zeros) are populated by values ranging from .0015 to .03.

Comment: If you want to verify result, I can upload the matrix later today.